# how to change the string value in android res/values/strings.xml ,

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Can you please guide someone how to change the app_version in strings.xml file which is reside in /src/main/res/values/strings.xml.

i want to change my strings.xml file

1.0.0.1

Changed App_version 1.0.0.1 to 1.0.0.2.

1.0.0.2

I have written some peace of code in build.gradle but not owrking properly.

please can you anyone help me

Comment: <string name="app_version">1.0.0.1</string> changed to <string name="app_version">1.0.0.2</string>

Answer (score 0):

You should have something similar in build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0.2"
}
```

Comment: Aha, this will not work for me, I have already autoincremented android:VersionName in build.gradle same result should be updated in strings.xml file. In strings.xml file my string content is

Comment: <string name="app_version">1.0.0.1</string> changed to <string name="app_version">1.0.0.2</string>

Comment: Please can you anyone quickly help me on this

Comment: I think you should just get the version like:  PackageInfo pInfo = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0); String version = pInfo.versionName;